# PHP String Replace between two html tags

Tags: php, html, string, str-replace

I am trying to replace text between two tags in a html document. I want to replace any text that isn't enclosed with a < and >.
I want to use str_replace to do this.

`php $string = '<html><h1> some text i want to replace</h1><p>some stuff i want to replace </p>';`

```
$text_to_echo = str_replace("Bla","Da",$String);
echo $text_to_echo;
```

Comment: I guess you need `Regex` to achieve this.

Comment: html is best handled by parsing it as XML. Some things can be achieved with regular expressions, but str_replace is not suitable for the task at all.

Comment: Obligatory link to "RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags" thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I would suggest you read this SO question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687778/replace-the-string-between-opening-and-closing-anchor-tags-with-some-other-strin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <?php

$string = '<html><h1> some text i want to replace</h1><p>
    some stuff i want to replace </p>';
$text_to_echo =  preg_replace_callback(
    "/(<([^.]+)>)([^<]+)(<\\/\\2>)/s", 
    function($matches){
        /*
         * Indexes of array:
         *    0 - full tag
         *    1 - open tag, for example <h1>
         *    2 - tag name h1
         *    3 - content
         *    4 - closing tag
         */
        // print_r($matches);
        $text = str_replace(
           array("text", "want"), 
           array('TEXT', 'need'),
                $matches[3]
        );
        return $matches[1].$text.$matches[4];
    }, 
    $string
);
echo $text_to_echo;
```

Comment: Thanks, would there be a way to do this word by word. For example replace "text" with "hello" and "want" with "cake"

Comment: Hi. Would there be a easy way to implement MySQL with this as i want to fetch the arrays from a DB instead of having to manually insert them.

Comment: Hi, if you have in plan further to use these data, which were inserted in mysql, instead of replacing, then worth doing this one time.

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace()` can not handle this

You will need `regex` or `preg_replace` for that