# Replace text outside and inside HTML tags

Tags: php, html

Here's a sample of what I want to do.

Transform this:

```
 This is my sample <span id="my_id"><strong>text</strong></span> for Stackoverflow.
```

Into:

```
 I've replaced the text <span id="my_id"><strong>with something</strong></span> else.
```

In other words, I want to replace the text inside and outside HTML tags, without breaking the tags' positioning. This is a very simplistic example but the real world application might involve more complex nested tags.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use regex or preg_replace for your usecase.

Comment: Use an appropriate XML library. Do not parse XML with regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP String Replace between two html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962053/php-string-replace-between-two-html-tags)

Comment: Regex is a bad idea. You want to use an XML parser like [SimpleXML](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [DOM](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

```
// Create DOM from string
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');

$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';

$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';

echo $html; // Output: <div id="hello">foo</div><div id="world" class="bar">World</div>
```

As for your case:

```
$html = str_get_html('This is my sample <span id="my_id"><strong>text</strong></span> for Stackoverflow.');

$html->find('span[id=my_id]', 0)->innertext = 'with something';
```

As for the text around the tag, you can iterate on every text with:

```
$html->find('text')
```

This would return an array of the elements, 'this is my sample', 'yourhtmlcode....' and 'for stackoverflow'.