# how to replace duplicate text using highlight_phrase in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter but I am trying to learn it. I am trying to replace a text with an anchor tag.

```
But the problem is if the text inside the <a> tag has the property of href,
```

it also replaced. I want only to replace the text inside the anchor tag and does not include the href. here is my code.

```
<?php 

  $string = "text1 text1-a text1-b";
  $array  = explode(' ', $string);
  $tofind = "text1";
  foreach($array as $value){
     $string = highlight_phrase($string,$tofind,"<a href=\"{$value}\">","</a>"); 
  }
  echo $string;
 ?>

 //The output should be
 // <a href="text1">text1</a> text1-a text1-b

 // but the **WRONG** result is it also replace the "text1" inside the href.
 // <a href="text1">text1</a> 
 // <a href="<a href="text1"></a>-a">text1-a</a>
 // <a href="<a href="text1"></a>-a">text2-a</a>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? thanks

Comment: I would change the way anchor is generated, so lets say you have `$array` already try using [array_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php), further more try using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead of codeigniters `highlight_phrase`.

Comment: @Kyslik, thanks for the suggestion. However, I dont know how to do it in preg_replace, do you have idea? .. thanks

Comment: please try editing question and add tag `regex` more people might come, I am not regex expert I usually google patterns to fit my needs. Also please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8690420/1564365 .
I highly recommend to reconsider how you generate link. If you have an array do array search/replace if you have string do string replace...